# Visual Studio 2013 JS HTML Template

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

before i reinstalled visual studio i had an option to choose a blank html/js only template. There is still an option for a blank JS project but it's different and it seems like it's supposed for windows 8 store apps.

I found a picture from a typescript template. I had the same option for javascript:

[image: TypeScript HTML Template]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-15-70/2654.2.png))</sub>

Now it's gone and I'd like to have it back. Maybe someone can help me out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to restore the default project templates so as to fix your problem.

In the command prompt, navigate to the location of devenv.exe. This file is located in `<Visual Studio Installation Path>\Common7\IDE.`

Note:
If you are running Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must open the command prompt as an administrator

Type `"devenv /installvstemplates"` and press Enter.

Note:
If you are using an Express Edition of Visual Studio, type `"<ExpressName>Express /installvstemplates"` where `<ExpressName>` is either VB or VCS for Visual Basic and Visual C#, respectively.

By default, templates installed together with the product are located in:

```
\VisualStudioInstallationDirectory\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\Language\Locale\
\VisualStudioInstallationDirectory\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\Language\Locale\
```

For example, the following directory contains the Visual Studio project templates for English:

```
C:\VisualStudioInstallationDirectory\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic\1033\
```

Try to empty them first and then reinstall .If this procedure does not restore the default templates, reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm using VS2013 Professional. I tried your advice but still got the same templates. This is a 2nd computer and I had an express edition installed before, maybe thats the source of evil?

Comment: Check the folders i mention above and try to empty first before the action /Manual delete the foders of visual studio xpress .Seems that there are somewhere located .